# Custom Registration

Tags: wordpress, registration, user-registration

I need to create a custom registration flow and am a bit stuck.

The requirements are as follows:

- 1 role for all user (Vendor as per WC Vendors)
- 3 types of users (Wholesale, Retail, Private)
- Different profile fields for each type
- Different registration form for each type
- Different profile page (Buddypress) for each type

Also

- I need that the user sign up with minimal details but then force the user to complete their profile in order to be able to use the site (sell products).

So far I have seen many custom form plugins such as Ninja forms and Gravity Forms as well as a couple of front end form plugins such as WP User Frontend and Profile builder but I don't know which one to choose!!!

Any help, advice, support would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Eyal